# Trying to figure out how can I log live bandwith usage of a streaming server using speedometer or vnstat

Tags: debian, streaming, bandwidth

I'm currently running a test environnement for a streaming web-radio device, and have to monitor live bandwith usage to see what kind of plan I can get from a hosting-service as of bandwith limitation.

The server is currently running Debian 8 with Icecast2 and Ices2. I did mount a VM simulating 10 concurrent connections to the radio to have some upload data, but I want to see how much bw it uses on a hour/day average.

Can't seem to find what I'm looking for with classic monitoring tools, and live bandwitch analysis tools don't allow me to log the data.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a good use case for VNStat:

> vnStat is a console-based network traffic monitor for Linux and BSD that keeps a log of network traffic for the selected interface(s). It uses the network interface statistics provided by the kernel as information source. This means that vnStat won't actually be sniffing any traffic and also ensures light use of system resources.

More info here: http://humdi.net/vnstat/